# Using a php variable to insert values into a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use a variable to insert into multiple tables.  When I hard code the specific table name it runs properly, when I use a variable I get a QUERY FAILEDSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 error.  dbname is the variable.  I am using a for loop to change the name of the table.  For example table 1 is budget1000, then budget 2000 etc. Here is my code

```
$sql='INSERT INTO ".$dbName." VALUES(:id,:category,:subCategory,
:amount, :today,:description,   :year)';


try{
$st= $conn->prepare($sql);
$st->bindValue(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st->bindValue(":category", $category, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st->bindValue(":subCategory", $subCategory, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st->bindValue(":amount", $amount, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st->bindValue(":today", $today, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->bindValue(":description", $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->bindValue(":year", $year, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$st->execute();
}catch(PDOException $e ){
echo "QUERY FAILED" . $e->getMessage();
```

}

Comment: you should use only one table, not a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$sql='INSERT INTO '.$dbName.' VALUES(:id,:category,:subCategory,:amount, :today,:description,   :year)';
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  Changed from double quotes to single quotes and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's a quote mismatch, you start off with single quotes but then switch to double quotes when you concatenate the DB name into your string.  Try replacing the single quotes at the beginning and end of your $sql string with double quotes and remove the periods around $dbname, or use single quotes all the way through.